# Add elements to jquery object inside each loop

Tags: jquery

I'm sure i'm missing something here, using this code:

```
var $divs = $();
$.each([1, 2, 3], function (i, val) {
    $divs.add($('<div>' + val + '</div>'));
});
alert($divs.length); //output 0 { not really expected }
```

`$divs` is empty object.

To get expected behaviour, i need to reaffect to var `$divs` like this:

```
var $divs = $();
$.each([1, 2, 3], function (i, val) {
    $divs = $divs.add($('<div>' + val + '</div>'));
});
alert($divs.length); //output 3 { as expected }
```

Could someone explain me why? What is the correct way of doing this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CV4pU/)

[add() jquery's method](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

**EDIT**

Finally, this is expected behaviour as all of you pointed it. This is in fact correct to keep matched set unchanged. It's like using value not reference to the set of matched objects.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9055

Comment: Ok, seems like expected behaviour, really strange IMO: "This is not a bug, it's the way .add has always worked. .add does *not* mutate the original set, it returns a new set. If you want to save the result into the original variable, you have to use an assignment."

Comment: Ok, guys, should have read more carefully the doc, sorry!

Comment: I'm quite suprised this was closed. Voted to re-open..

Comment: @Zenith seems fair, i should have read the doc ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs (that you provided):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
> .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
> elements and the ones passed into the method.

And

> The following will not save the added elements, because the .add()
> method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv
> unchanged:
>
> var pdiv = $("p");
>
> pdiv.add("div");  // WRONG, pdiv will not change

Answer (score 2):

This was actually [**reported as a bug**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9055) to the jQuery team - this was the response from a jQuery team member:

> "This is not a bug, it's the way `.add` has always worked. `.add` does
>   *not* mutate the original set, it returns a new set. If you want to save the result into the original variable, you have to use an
>   assignment - for example, `coll = coll.add(foo)`."

Answer (score 1):

add() does not change the original object,instead it returns a new object.

Here is the part from the jquery docs that explains it

> The following will not save the added elements, because the .add()
>   method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv
>   unchanged:
>
> `var pdiv = $("p"); pdiv.add("div"); // WRONG, pdiv will not change`

http://api.jquery.com/add/#add-elements

Answer (score 1):

> because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original
>   set unchanged:

From [add() jquery's method](http://api.jquery.com/add/)